# Rails 5: Why isn't my custom error message working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named `Listing`. It has an attribute called `application_url` and I'm trying to set a custom error message for it.

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  validate :application_method_present?

  def application_method_present?
    # ...
    errors.add(:application_url, :invalid)
  end
end
```

So far, the error message looks like this:

```
    @messages=
    {
        :application_url=>["is invalid"]
    }
```

I want to change *"is invalid"* to something else. To that end, I have added the following to `en.yml`:

```
    en:
      errors:
        models:
          listing:
            attributes:
              application_url:
                invalid: "IS ERRORED!"
```

But that is has no effect. I've checked in the console and on the site, after restarting the server, but the default error message is still display.

Is there an obvious reason why my custom message isn't being set? How should I set a custom message?

Comment: why cant you give the error message directly like this  `@user.errors.add(:application_url, "Not valid")`?

Comment: Yes, I can but it's not what I want to do. I should have mentioned that the reason I want to set it in the yaml is that I want to eventually change the format for particular error messages so that they aren't prepended with the attribute name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably override this message: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      invalid: "is invalid"
```

but it will override all `invalid` errors. So some custom translation would be better in my opinion:

```
errors.add(:application_url, I18n.t("errors.application_url.invalid"))
```

or try with `activerecord` key:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        listing:
          attributes:
            application_url:
              invalid: "IS ERRORED!"
```

Comment: The `activerecord` key was what I needed.